# Model stops at loss.backward() with "Illegal instruction prompt"

Tags: image, classification, pytorch

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59245714/9481957) but OP states his programme ran successfully on linux, while my problem is on Ubuntu. I've tried downgrading both torch and torchvision and the problem persists. The part I suspect that causes the problem is shown below:

```
for epoch in range(max_epoch):

    running_loss = 0.0
    for image, label in train_loader:

        optimiser.zero_grad()

        output = model(image)

        print("Label:{}\n".format(label))
        print("Output is {}\n".format(output))

        loss = criterion(output,label)
        print("Loss is {}".format(loss.item()))
        loss.backward()
        print("Backward loss and now optimiser")
        optimiser.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
        print("Loss: {:.4f}".format(running_loss))
```

The full code is available [here](http://github.com/abbaahmad/meterR-CNN)
Here's the prompt I get:
[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYvFa.png)

Comment: There's a thread talking about that [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/15012)

Comment: Thanks for that. Seems there's little anyone here can do

Comment: What's the SO, environment, and pytorch version?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, pip, torch 1.4.0 cpu && torchvision 0.5.0 cpu. These are the lastest version of torch, plus I used the preceding versions also.

Comment: Pretty much the same here. Can you create a virtual env and try to replicate this error there? Also, can you move everything to GPU and see what happens?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don&amp;amp;#39;t have a GPU. Plus, Im working in a virtual environment. Havent tried on system Python as of yet, but I did try with different Python versions.